# Connecting to the socket server

Tags: java, sockets

I made poor socket server.What i need to do if i want connect to my server from my neighbor computer,and did he only need my client.java class or both with server.java?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("connecting");

        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4031);
        Socket ss = s.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        DataInputStream dout = new DataInputStream(ss.getInputStream());
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true) {
            String yoo = dout.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client: "+yoo);
            if(yoo.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        ss.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want your neighbor to be the server? then he only need the code to listen to incoming connections.. and do make sure you can reach your neighbor computer directly, lest you may need something fancy such as port forwarding.

Comment: What is your _client.java class_?

Comment: public class Client {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  Socket s = new Socket("MyPublicIP",4031);
  DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  while(true) {
   String so = br.readLine();
   dout.writeUTF(so);
   if(so.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
    break;
   }
  }
  s.close();

 }
 
 
}